# MUI makeStyles() class applied but styles not reflecting when using classList.add('class-name')

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, file-upload, material-ui

I am using `MUI makeStyles()` to write a bunch of CSS classes. And out of these classes, I am dynamically adding and removing one class to my `Box` element on file `drag-and-drop` events.

The class is successfully applied and I can even see it getting applied while I drag a file over my element. However, I can't see the styles inside the class being applied to my element. I am not sure what is going wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code snippet -

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  imageUploader: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    gap: '8px',
    padding: '24px 16px',
    border: '1px dashed #AAAAAA',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  imageUploaderDrop: {
    background: '#e4e4e4',
  },
});

export default function ImageUploader() {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const imageUploaderContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const imageUploader = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const classList = () => imageUploaderContainer.current?.classList;

  const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    classList()?.remove('imageUploaderDrop');
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!classList()?.contains('imageUploaderDrop')) {
      classList()?.add('imageUploaderDrop');
    }
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    if (classList()?.contains('imageUploaderDrop')) {
      classList()?.remove('imageUploaderDrop');
    }
  };

return (
    <Box
      className={styles.imageUploader}
      onClick={() => imageUploader.current?.click()}
      onDrop={handleDrop}
      onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
      onDragOver={handleDragOver}
      ref={imageUploaderContainer}
    >
      ...
    </Box>
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, not images.

Comment: okay let me share it as text

Comment: @InSync I have updated the images to code snippet (as text)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid className collisions, `MUI makeStyles` generates dynamic classes with a random ID appended to them. For example, in our case it would be something like `makeStyles-imageUploaderDrop-62`.

And since here, when I was using `classList.add('imageUploaderDrop')` although it was applying to the DOM, it was not exactly the same as the dynamic className. And hence the class styles were not visible.

To solve this problem, one can directly access the dynamic classNames from the `useStyles()` hook. And can add and remove it using the classList method.

```
const styles = useStyles();
element.classList.add(styles.imageUploaderDrop);
```